# route path terminal 'loading' issue

Tags: node.js, indexing, terminal

when trying to run Node.js in the terminal (node index.js) to run some code, I have this issue in my file path where it says 'loading'. It still gives me my output but my terminal freezes at this point. I have to keep killing the terminal to be able to run the terminal again. Why is this?

[Image of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDg3E.png)

Comment: [Don't show images of text](/help/how-to-ask). Put the text in your post, as text, with appropriate [markdown](/markdown) like code fences.